# FlexBox React Native How to align an item to the bottom of the page

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I want to align a row of four dotted items to the bottom of the page.

[image]

I tried to use flexGrow and alignSelf but the element just move to the right of the screen.
This is my code so far.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`flexGrow: 1` is usually only required if you are in a `scrollView`, otherwise, wrap the bottom component in `View` with `style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}`.

Comment: I did that when i did i lost my flexbox row and my 4 dotted circle stack like a column

Comment: how about adding `flexDirection: row`?

Comment: I created a View wrapping the steplist array and when i added the style you mention it didn't work and when i added the flex row. my items went to the right

Comment: Wrap that View with `<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>`